# My rand() isn't really working in C++ specifically in Visual Studio 2019. I do have had "include <time.h> and <stdlib.h>

Tags: c++, visual-studio, random

My rand() gives out the same number (GPA) for every student.

```cpp
srand(time(NULL));
    int gpa = 0 + (rand() % (10 - 0 + 1));

    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        cout << "Enter the student #" << i + 1 << "'s name: ";
        getline(cin, pStudents[i]); cout << endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        cout << "Student " << pStudents[i] << " has GPA of: " << gpa << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Why not use what is available in `<random>`?

Comment: Please descrive your expected behavior and actual behavior. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) without any undeclared variables.

Comment: What does "isn't really working" mean? What do you expect to happen? What's happening instead? One possibility: If you expect each student to have a different GPA, you'll need to call `rand()` more than once instead of precomputing a single value for `gpa` and assigning it to every single student.

Comment: it is the rand() which gives out the same number of GPA for every student.

Comment: This code only computes `gpa` once. Sounds like perhaps you want to compute it for each iteration of your last `for` loop.

Comment: Yes Andy. But how can i have a different random number GPA for every student .

Comment: Also, `0 + (rand() % (10 - 0 + 1));` can probably just be `rand() % 10 + 1`

Comment: Assigning students random grade point averages (GPA), (and one that goes from 0 to 10 rather than 0 to 4 at that), is not a great way to make an understandable example.  It's kind of surreal conceptually.

Comment: Call `srand` only once at the beginning of `main`. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once

Comment: `int gpa = 0 + (rand() % (10 - 0 + 1));` does not declare a symbolic expression, to be evaluated on each call to `gpa`. If you want something like that, you should use a function `int gpa() { return 0 + (rand() % (10 - 0 + 1)); }`. As is, your code calculates GPA once, and reuses the same value on every loop iteration.

Comment: hahaha thanks John. That is way more convenient.

Comment: @Tri_Hai05 The `rand()` function is poor.  Use the updated C++ <random> functions, as [shown here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e555508002948641)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only compute it once.

Here is how to fix it on your code:

```
srand(time(NULL));
for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    cout << "Enter the student #" << i + 1 << "'s name: ";
    getline(cin, pStudents[i]); cout << endl;
}
for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    int gpa = 0 + (rand() % (10 - 0 + 1));
    cout << "Student " << pStudents[i] << " has GPA of: " << gpa << endl;
}
```

Comment: OP doesn't need to `srand` each loop iteration.

Comment: I don't believe I've ever seen a screenshot of code in an answer. Please post all code as text.

Comment: oh thanks. i can't really give u a vote but someone will do =)).

Comment: It's a screenshot of code that doesn't match the question or the rest of the answer. How is that a helpful addition to your answer? Once you moved the `srand` out of the loop it was fine.

Comment: okay, edited it.